# Need help with a .conf file to run a lighting node?

Tags: lightning-network, eclair

This is my configuration file and i followed all of the instructions for the program but it always gives me the error message about something missing. I don't even know what programming language .conf files are written in. if someone can give me some guidance that would be much appreciated.

`eclair.chain=mainnet
eclair.bitcoind.rpcport=8332
eclair.bitcoind.rpcuser=foo
eclair.bitcoind.rpcpassword=bar
eclair.server.port=9735
eclair.node-alias=<myalias>
eclair.node-color=00ff00
eclair.bitcoind.zmq="tcp://127.0.0.1:29000"`

Answer (score 0):

I got this code from https://medium.com/@crypto_coffee/how-to-set-up-a-bitcoin-lightning-node-b54733fbcb7f.

```
eclair.chain=mainnet
eclair.node-alias=”node-alias”
eclair.bitcoind.rpcport=8332
eclair.bitcoind.rpcuser=username
eclair.bitcoind.rpcpassword=password
eclair.bitcoind.zmq=”tcp://127.0.0.1:29000"
eclair.server.public-ips = [“xxx.xxx.xx.x”]
eclair.node-color=”ffffff"
```

Just replace the generic text with your computer's info.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about the eclair implementation, but in LND when running the node it looks for lnd.conf which is stored in ~/.lnd by default.